# Crash with QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()

Tags: c++, qt, model, qt5

I've been searching all around for a solution to this problem and I'm starting to believe this can be a bug in the Qt function itself. 
The problem is that after you call QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes() the program will crash when the program tries to destruct the QModelIndexList that this function returns. Before the crash, you get the following debug message:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   (…)
>   File: 
>   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
>   Line:1419
>   Expression:
>   _pFirstBlock == pHead
>   (…)

Here is the simplest code that will cause the problem, so you can test it by yourself:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QModelIndexList>
#include <QListView>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>

void doSomethingWithSelection(QItemSelectionModel* selectionmodel);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringList list;
    list.push_back("1");
    list.push_back("2");
    list.push_back("3");
    list.push_back("4");
    QStringListModel model(list);
    QListView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);

    QItemSelectionModel *selectionmodel = view.selectionModel();
    QModelIndex first = model.index(0);
    QModelIndex last = model.index(2);
    QItemSelection selection(first, last);
    selectionmodel->select(selection,QItemSelectionModel::Select);

    doSomethingWithSelection(selectionmodel);

    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}

void doSomethingWithSelection(QItemSelectionModel* selectionmodel)
{
    QModelIndexList indexlist = selectionmodel->selectedIndexes();
    // this is what causes the error. I put this inside a function
    // so the error will happen when exiting the function,
    // when the program try to destroy the list nodes.
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can work with QItemSelectionModel only in Qt loop. Could you try to call doSomethingWithSelection after a.exec()?

Comment: Well, I really don't know what you mean when you say "only in Qt loop".. but about calling after a.exec(), this is not possible, because a.exec() is what starts the application loop and everything happens inside this function. After it the program returns.

Comment: Under "in Qt loop" I mean the application loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem only that I am using selected rows instead of selected indexes. I narrowed it down to function exit when the internal QList in QModelIndexList tries to delete the indexes from the heap. Not sure how to fix it but I read this interesting post [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/13355/qt4-qtableview-assertion-failure.html?s=24b87570d6036bd20b1c317228385143d7ee4b5b) and came up with this function:

```
QModelIndexList Class::getViewSelection(QAbstractItemView *view ,  int columnNumber) const
{
  QModelIndexList list;
  for (int row = 0; row < view->model()->rowCount(view->rootIndex()); ++row)
  {
    QModelIndex index = view->model()->index(row, columnNumber, view->rootIndex());

    if (view->selectionModel()->isSelected(index))
        list.push_back(index);
   }
  return list;
}
```

I wrote this function to get selected rows so the column parameter is the column you want the index for.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `QTreeView` and accessing `selectedIndexes()` or anything in `selectionModel()`.

It was **fixed** when I used the correct `/MD` compiler switch with the correct `Qt` libraries.

To fix the crash:

- compile your code with `/MDd` and link with debug `Qt libs` (example `Qt5Cored.lib`
- compile your code with `/MD` and link with release `Qt libs` (example `Qt5Core.lib`)

Comment: I experienced this with Qt 5.6 debug builds for WEC2013 using the /MTd flag. Release builds compiled with /MT flag were stable. However, the product when built with /MD flag booted in almost half the time, which was a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, but right now I don’t understande why this works, yet: (I'm writing this as an answer hoping that it can help someone with the same problem)

In my Qt project, I was using a Kit with ***Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.0.7600.16385.40715) (x86)*** as compiler. When I changed the compiler to ***Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0 (x86)*** this code worked correctly.

As I said, I don't know why this works and if someone can explain this to me I will be happy to hear. I don't know even why Windows SDK is listed as a compiler.. it is not, is it?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same error, but your solution is not working in my case. Is there any other solution you know of?

Comment: Same issue... And the only workaround that I found is to create a new QModelIndexList (If you delete this pointer the crash reappear...) "QModelIndexList *indexes = new QModelIndexList(m_listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes());"